# Получение непонятного элемента при работе с коллекциями

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, коллекции

Задача стоит в том, чтобы полученный на вход массив чисел, преобразовав в список, увеличить его четные числа на единицу. Затем вернуть кусок с 3 по 7 элемент.
Никак не могу понять в чем проблема. Почему тест получает 1, а не 57?!

```java
public static List<Integer> task2(Integer... array) {
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(asList(array));
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0){
                list.set(i, +1);
            }
        }
       return list.subList(2, 7);
    }
}
```

```java
@Test
void task2() {
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(57, 23, 43, 95, 13),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(23, 15, 1, 56, 22, 42, 95, 13, 9)
        );
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(5, 7, 5, 7, 5),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7)
        );
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(5, -7, 15, 27, 5),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(0, -4, 7, 4, -7, 14, 27, 4, -27)
        );
        assertIterableEquals(
                Arrays.asList(15, 27, 5),
                Lesson10_CollectionsLists.task2(0, 7, 4, 14, 27, 4)
        );
    }
```

```java
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: iterable contents differ at index [0], expected: <57> but was: <1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходить из тест кейсов, то решение должно быть примерно таким:

```
public static List<Integer> task2(Integer... array) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) % 2 == 0) {
            list.set(i, list.get(i) + 1);
        }
    }
    return list.size() >= 8 ? list.subList(3, 8) : list.subList(3, list.size());
}
```